# Is cmd-key-happy dead on OS X 10.6.6?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I've been a happy user of cmd-key-happy for running emacs -nw on my Mac. After upgrading to 10.6.6 and rebooting, cmd-key-happy seems to run, but doesn't seem to function. There isn't much in the way of support or mailing lists for the tool itself, so I figured I'd at least post here to see if the problem is a general one or mine. Does anyone know if cmd-key-happy has a problem with 10.6.6?

Answer (score 2):

Working fine for me on 10.6.6.

Is there anything in the logs that indicates a problem:

```
grep cmd-key-happy /var/log/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know no one's going to believe me, but it started working again mid-day unprompted. Seriously -- I had an emacs -nw session going in Terminal, I cmd-tabbed away to do something else, and when I came back, cmd-key-happy had started working. Weird. But thanks for pointing me toward the logs; not finding anything there still told me something.

Comment: Oddly, I'm having a similar problem. Running cmd-key-happy master for weeks without issue, then today I noticed my meta keystrokes were backwards. Daemon running without error. Restart daemon. Problem persists. Guess I'll reboot or otherwise wait for it to start working again. I do see this in system.log: Jan 19 14:11:04 alpha cmd-key-happy[203]: kCGEventTapDisabledByTimeout, Enabling Event Tap. But it seems to happen periodically and apparently doesn't cause a problem.

Comment: As a follow-up, rebooting seems to have fixed it.

Comment: As another follow-up, I have isolated the issue to a conflict with Google Chrome.  I'm not sure why exactly, but restarting Chrome seems to resolve the issue (without restarting cmd-key-happy, btw).  Chrome version 9.0.597.107.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not broken by 10.6, but it may have a conflict with Google Chrome.  I had similar symptoms (had been running fine for a long time, then noticed it wasn't functioning even though the process was running, and cmd-key-happy-restart didn't fix it), but restarting Google Chrome fixed cmd-key-happy.  Thanks to Drew R.'s comment on a different answer here for pointing that out.